# Can I run a modern version of Ubuntu on VirtualBox with my Celeron processor?

Tags: virtualbox, 32-bit

I am running VirtualBox 6.0.8 under Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I have a Intel Celeron N3060 processor which I think may be causing some problems.

I planned to run Ubuntu in the VM. However:

16.04.6 32-bit hangs on installation.
14.04.6 32-bit will not load and eventually is "aborted" by VirtualBox.
12.04.5 32-bit works fine but support ended in April 2017.

I can only assume that my processor is so limited that I need a basic stripped down version of Linux.

Can anyone please suggest an Ubuntu-like OS which is supported by the manufacturer and which will run under my processor in VirtualBox?

Or perhaps there is an alternative way to get Ubuntu running under the VM? Thanks.

Comment: Define "modern". Have you looked at lubuntu and/or xubuntu but I do believe virtualbox with a celeron will be strechting it. There are i3 notebooks 2nd hand that do not cost that much and would be a serious improvement over a celeron ;)

Comment: Did you verify your ISOs before you tried to use them?  You mention Ubuntu 14.04.6 which is EOL too, and flavors based on 16.04 are now EOL (LTS flavor desktops have 3 years of support, and 16.04 is from 2016.April so now only Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity is fully supported though packages used by say Lubuntu that are common with main Ubuntu still receive updates, which doesn't include desktop & gui programs).

Comment: How much ram do you have?

Comment: @Rinzwind I agree that Celeron is hardly stellar. Do you have any suggestions for a decent second hand notebook? I would erase Windows and replace it with Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc I always check the SHA256 hash so yes I did verify them. I've never used any other version of Ubuntu but I suspect that Lubuntu or whatever isn't going to work well with the Celeron even though its not "pure" Ubuntu.

Comment: @crip659 I have 4GB.

Comment: Most main OSs will say they will work with a minimum of 2gb, they don't say they will work well with that.  You are trying to use an OS plus another OS in virtualbox.  Do you need to use it in virtualbox or maybe do a dual boot and have each OSs have the full 4gb, need about 30gb hard drive space plus extra for downloads.  Lubuntu or Xubuntu are lighter versions good for older/weaker hardware.

Comment: Just out of interest, is it a big deal to run an unsupported version e.g. 12.04 in a VM (i.e. not in the actual host OS)? Does it matter?

Comment: That is probably the best way since stuff that old does not get any security or any updates anymore, also this site does not like to deal with non supported ubuntu OSs.  Other than that, go for it.  Not good idea to use it banking or stuff like that.